# Deallocating memory

Tags: c++, memory, delete-operator

For a project I have to implement a bitset class. My code thus far is:

Header File

```
#ifndef BITSET_H_
#define BITSET_H_
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

// Container class to hold and manipulate bitsets
class Bitset {
public:
    Bitset();
    Bitset(const string);
    ~Bitset();

    // Returns the size of the bitset
    int size();

    // Sets a bitset equal to the specified value
    void operator= (const string);

    // Accesses a specific bit from the bitset
    bool operator[] (const int) const;

private:
    unsigned char *bitset;
    int set_size;
    // Sets a bitset equal to the specified value
    void assign(const string);
};
#endif /* BITSET_H_ */
```

Source File

```
#include "bitset.h"

Bitset::Bitset() {
    bitset = NULL;
}

Bitset::Bitset(const string value) {
    bitset = NULL;
    assign(value);
}

Bitset::~Bitset() {
    if (bitset != NULL) {
        delete[] bitset;
    }
}

int Bitset::size() {
    return set_size;
}

void Bitset::operator= (const string value) {
    assign(value);
}

bool Bitset::operator[] (const int index) const {
    int offset;

    if (index >= set_size) {
        return false;
    }

    offset = (int) index/sizeof(unsigned char);
    return (bitset[offset] >> (index - offset*sizeof(unsigned char))) & 1;
}

void Bitset::assign(const string value) {
    int i, offset;

    if (bitset != NULL) {
        delete[] bitset;
    }

    bitset = new unsigned char[(int) ceil(value.length()/sizeof(unsigned char))];

    for (i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        offset = (int) i/sizeof(unsigned char);
        if (value[i] == '1') {
            bitset[offset] |= (1 << (i - offset*sizeof(unsigned char)));
        } else {
            bitset[offset] &= ~(1 << (i - offset*sizeof(unsigned char)));
        }
    }

    set_size = value.length();
}
```

My problem is my delete statements in both the deconstructor and assign method core dump. Is it not necessary to deallocate this memory? From what I've read so far it's always necessary to use the delete command whenever you call new.

**EDIT:** I've changed the code above to reflect one of the fixes. I added bitset = NULL in the constructor. This fixed the core dump in the assign method however I'm still getting errors in the deconstructor.

Comment: Side note: `sizeof(unsigned char)` is always `1`, probably you wanted `std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits` or `CHAR_BIT` instead. Also the division of two integers yields another integer (truncating any fractions).

Comment: Brian's found a critical bug. sth above found another.  Note too that you're allocating 8 times as many bytes as necessary: sizeof is in bytes not bits. (I think it'd be easier to read if you include <inttypes.h> if your system has it, and use int8_t, else typedef it yourself, then you can just assume sizeof == 1). E.g. `bitset = new int8_t[(value.size() + 7) / 8]`.

Comment: Thanks sth for pointing that out. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: you've accepted one answer but commented that it didn't solve your problem, "the delete statement in my deconstructor still fails". My answer (0 votes so far, after a day) probably solves your problem. Just FYI... Cheers,

Comment: This class uses a resource (the dynamic array) *and* tries to manage it. This is bad. Either manage the resource, or use the resource. You have `std::vector` for the former, therefore you should just be using `std::vector` for your resource. This solves your problems considerably. (Obviously you'd use `std::bitset` too, in real code.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should initialize `bitset` to `NULL` in your second constructor.

Why?

Because a pointer variable won't necessarily be initialized to `NULL`.  So you may be trying to `delete[]` some random memory address when you use that second constructor.

So you should have:

```
Bitset::Bitset(const string value) : bitset(NULL)
{
    assign(value);
}
```

Comment: +1, `bitset` isn't initialized explicitly before its use in `assign`, so it has some garbage address in it.

Comment: Good call. That fixed the core dump I get in the assign method however the delete statement in my deconstructor still fails.

Comment: @blcArmadillo, I have a simple `main` function that just creates a `Bitset` using the string constructor, and with Brian's code the coredumping is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're copying a `Bitset` somewhere. You have not defined a copy constructor, not a copy assignment operator. The result of copying is then that you have two instances who both think they should deallocate the dynamically allocated array when they finish.

This is known as the **Rule of Three**: if you define any of destructor, copy constructor or copy assignment operator, then chances are that you'll need to define *all three*.

Now, about your code:

```
#include "bitset.h"
```

OK.

```
Bitset::Bitset() {
    bitset = NULL;
}
```

(1) You didn't include a header that guaranteed defines `NULL`.

(2) you're not initializing the member `set_size`, so the check in the index operator may/will be using an indeterminate value, with Undefined Behavior.

(3) generally prefer to use initializer list rather than assignment (this avoids e.g. doing default construction followed by assignment).

```
Bitset::Bitset(const string value) {
    bitset = NULL;
    assign(value);
}
```

(4) Generally it's not a good idea to express construction in terms of assignment. Instead, express assignment in terms of construction.

```
Bitset::~Bitset() {
    if (bitset != NULL) {
        delete[] bitset;
    }
}
```

(5) The check for `NULL` is unnecessary; you can safely `delete` a nullpointer.

```
int Bitset::size() {
    return set_size;
}
```

(6) Uh, well, `set_size` was the member that wasn't initialized… Also, this member function should be `const`.

```
void Bitset::operator= (const string value) {
    assign(value);
}
```

(7) An assignment operator should in general return a reference to the assigned-to object. That's just a convention, but it's what users of your class expect.

(8) Pass an in-argument by value or by reference to `const`. Generally, for built-in types choose by-value and for other types, such as `std::string`, choose reference to `const`. That is, the formal argument should better be `string const& value`.

```
bool Bitset::operator[] (const int index) const {
    int offset;

    if (index >= set_size) {
        return false;
    }

    offset = (int) index/sizeof(unsigned char);
    return (bitset[offset] >> (index - offset*sizeof(unsigned char))) & 1;
}
```

(9) First, again, the uninitialized `set_size` member.

(10) Then, note that `sizeof(unsigned char)` is 1 by definition. You probably want to use `CHAR_BIT` from `<limits.h>` here. Or just use 8 unless you plan on supporting Unisys computers (9-bit byte) or perhaps a Texas Instruments digital signal processor (16-bit byte).

```
void Bitset::assign(const string value) {
    int i, offset;

    if (bitset != NULL) {
        delete[] bitset;
    }
```

(11) The check for `NULL` is unnecessary.

```
    bitset = new unsigned char[(int) ceil(value.length()/sizeof(unsigned char))];
```

(12) As already mentioned, `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.

(13) The division has integer arguments and so is an integer division, not a floating point division. Presumably what you want is the trick `(a+b-1)/b`?

```
    for (i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
```

(14) Style: declare a variable as close to its first use as practically possible. Here it means declare the loop counter `i` directly in the loop head, like this: `for( int i = 0, ...`.

```
        offset = (int) i/sizeof(unsigned char);
```

(14) And ditto for `offset`. But for this variable you're not planning on changing its value, so also declare it `const`.

```
        if (value[i] == '1') {
            bitset[offset] |= (1 << (i - offset*sizeof(unsigned char)));
        } else {
            bitset[offset] &= ~(1 << (i - offset*sizeof(unsigned char)));
        }
```

(15) Better rethink those shift operations!

```
    }

    set_size = value.length();
}
```

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the allocation size isn't zero, I suspect that's what's going on here, and that you're just writing to unallocated garbage memory. Running under valgrind will catch this too.